RxJS Observable, single success msg with concat operator
In the context of an Angular component I have 2 observables.
Requirements

I want to execute both in sequence.
If the first observable fails I don't want to run the second
If either fail, I want to log a single error msg
If both succeed, I want to log a single success msg

Approach

I am using concat to achieve #1 and #2
I am capturing #3 in the error notification of the concat subscription. There will only ever be 1 error notification to process due to concat
#4 is where the problem lies. I cannot use next on the concat subscription as it will log a success msg per observable. I can handle this in the complete notification of the concat subscription but that is not typically where you would handle success. There's a code smell off this approach.

What is the best way to achieve my requirements?
    getData1$ = this.myService.getData1();
    getData2$ = this.myService.getData2();
    
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
      this.getAllData();
    }
    
    getAllData() {
      concat(this.getData1$, this.getData2$)
      .pipe(finalize(() => console.log('always called')))
      .subscribe(() => {
        error: console.log('one or more data fetches have had an error');
        complete: console.log('all data fetches have succeeded');
      });}


Use a concat, it will execute in series one by one, then we can use toArray which will collect all source emissions and emits them as an array when the source completes.
getData1$ = this.myService.getData1();
getData2$ = this.myService.getData2();

constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  this.getAllData();
}

getAllData() {
  concat(this.getData1$, this.getData2$).pipe(toArray())
  .subscribe({
    next: (data: any) => console.log('success!'),
    error: () => console.log('one or more data fetches have had an error'),
    complete: () => console.log('all data fetches have succeeded'),
  });
}

Stackblitz Demo

Hi Naren, thank you for your reply. However the solution in the Stackblitz demo provided does not address the requirements. You can see if one of the observables throws an error for example, it does not adhere to the requirements

@Fred2020 please share back the stackblitz with the failing scenario and what needs to be fixed, as far as I can see my code matches your requirements stackblitz with failing observable

Try .... const arraySource = concat(
of(1),
throwError(new Error('Error'))
).pipe(toArray());

@Fred2020 it works stackblitz

My apologies, it does work with that error handler added

What about the requirement "If the first observable fails I don't run the second"? In you example, the second observable is most likely called even if not subscribed to (HttpService produces hot observables)

@Liero There is not way to convert a completed API to a failed API, this is an example not a API all, but will work if you work with api calls

With the following code I achieved your desired result in Angular 18: 
    concat(this.getData1$, this.getData2$)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)) // You dont need it, but it wouldnt hurt.
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          //This logs if a request is successful.
          console.log(res);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          //This logs if a request is NOT successful.
          console.log('Error');
        },
        complete: () => {
          //This logs if ALL requests are successful.
          console.log('Complete');
        },
      });

This will run the Observables in sequence. 
If one fails it will log the error and stop. 
If it runs through it will log each response and log complete at the end. 
The only thing missing would be finalize since I got errors on the subscribe with that. 
So, whats different from your Code? 
Instead of .subscribe(() => {...}) I use .subscribe({...})
This is what I use for the destroy$ btw:
    destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.destroy$.next();
      this.destroy$.complete();
    }


"If it runs through it will log each response and log complete at the end." This fails requirement 4

@Fred2020 Just remove the log inside the next. Then it will not log each response and would fullfill all your requirements.

I'm not sure I follow, as per requirement 4 "If both succeed, I want to log a single success msg" ... so I do want a msg logged, a single one on both succeeding not 1 per successful run.

@Fred2020 Yes.
next logs for each request. error logs for each failed request. complete logs if all requests succeeded. So if you only want one log if both succeed, remove any log inside next. Then it will only log on errors or if both run through without problems.
